# To Check if a class can be typecast to another

Tags: c++, templates, casting, typecasting-operator

If I have a template function

```
template<class T, class U>
T foo (U a);
```

How can I check If an object of class `U` can be type cast into an object `T`

That is If The class `U` has a member function

```
operator T(); // Whatever T maybe
```

Or the class `T` has a constructor

```
T(U& a); //ie constructs object with the help of the variable of type U
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [std::is_convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) (since C++11):

```
template<class T, class U>
T foo (U a) {
    if (std::is_convertible_v<U, T>) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
}
```

Note that `is_convertible_v` is added since C++17, if your compiler still doesn't support it you could use `std::is_convertible<U, T>::value` instead.

Comment: will that check for both constructor and type-cast operator?

Comment: @WARhead Yes, it will check both. If either of them exists then it will return `true`. For C++11, use `std::is_convertible<U, T>::value`.